# File Converters. How do they work?

Tags: php, html, server-side

how do file converters work? IE: Making a web application that will convert mp3 to ogg nearly instantly. This has always interested me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server has a program installed that does the conversion. The file is accepted, run (possibly with `exec('mp3-to-ogg tmpfile.mp3');` or similar), and passed back to be downloaded. It's quite simple, really, just as long as you have the program installed somewhere on the server where it can be run.

Comment: Any idea on how i could get started on making something like this? Just for knowledge

Comment: I look up stuff like that, but it just gives me links to converter websites. -_-
IE: http://goo.gl/E9gAh