# How does a file converter's WEBSITE works

Tags: file, converters, server-side

I have a question from a lot of time..
How does a file converter's website works?
I saw other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145341/file-converters-how-do-they-work) but i have not understood how it works.

If this question is ambiguous, vague or incomplete can you tell me what language that i have to study?

Comment: It's not about the language. The question is simply too broad because there is a multitude of technologies that sites like these can work with. The question you've linked pretty much explains the gist of their work, though.

Comment: i know but i want to make my personal website for improve my knowledge @Daniel Kamil Kozar